# why the tensorflow split function report error when X is a tensor

Tags: r, tensorflow, split

The tensorflow function split report error and I cannot figure it out

```r
X = tf$random_uniform(minval=0,
                      maxval=10,
                      shape(256, 32),
                      name = "X");
Y = tf$split(X, num_or_size_splits = 2, axis = 0)
```

the output are expected to be correct but it reports error message:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords):
>
> ValueError: 
>   Rank-0 tensors are not supported as the num_or_size_splits argument to split. 
>   Argument provided: 2.0

Comment: From the error it is stating that you have a `Rank-0 tensor`. It sounds very much like the input `X` has to be none-singular numerically.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine in tensorflow 1.14 with eager enabled:

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.enable_eager_execution()
X = tf.random_uniform(shape=(256, 32),minval=0,maxval=10,name = "X");
Y = tf.split(X, num_or_size_splits = 2, axis = 0)
```

if you are trying to use a tensor as num_or_size_splits make sure it's a list with elements indicating the size of each split

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.enable_eager_execution()
X = tf.random_uniform(shape=(256, 32),minval=0,maxval=10,name = "X");
n_split = tf.constant([128, 128])
Y= tf.split(X, num_or_size_splits = n_split, axis = 0)
```